# CPU Power throttling when gaming

Tags: cpu, windows-11, power, gaming, intel

I have a windows 11 laptop. When I stress test my CPU it draws 28 watt constantly. But when I open up a game it only draws 15 watts. Because of that I get bottle necked on CPU. My CPU frame time is generally 25-35ms while my GPU time is 15ms. How can I fix the power throttling problem on my CPU?

My system: Acer aspire A7 715-51G, CPU: i5-1240p, GPU: RTX 3050.

[image]

Comment: You likely have a shared cooling system between your CPU and GPU and your system is set up to limit the power and thus temperature below 70C to limit fan noise and prolong component life. Your fix below may give better performance but your CPU is 10 degrees hotter.

Comment: @Mokubai yeah possible. Its either thermal limits or dtt shifts cpu power to gpu while gaming. I tried to look at my dtt configuration but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disabling `intel dynamic tuning technology device extension component` on device manager and restarting the computer fixed the problem. Now it draws 28 watts while gaming. And my CPU frame times are better. And I get more FPS on games.

I believe its because intel dtt shifts CPU power to GPU like [in this image](https://images.anandtech.com/doci/12220/8.png)

[image: Device manager]
[image: HW info after the fix]
[image: intel dtt poster]